# Firebase Google Sign-In (Web) flow

Tags: javascript, web, firebase, firebase-authentication

[Ref this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin)

Hi all. Here is my code, I have two problems

First , I wanted to know my login flow is correct or not?

My logic is when user entered my index page

I will check user login state first

if user not login then asked user to login.

```
    function google_login_in(){
        var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider(); 
        provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login');
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
            var token = result.credential.accessToken;
            var user = result.user;
        }).catch(function(error) {
            var errorCode     = error.code;
            var errorMessage  = error.message;
            var email         = error.email;
            var credential    = error.credential;
        });         
    }

    function print_user(user) {
        user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
            console.log("Sign-in provider: "+profile.providerId);
            console.log("  Provider-specific UID: "+profile.uid);
            console.log("  Name: "+profile.displayName);
            console.log("  Email: "+profile.email);
            console.log("  Photo URL: "+profile.photoURL);
        });
    }

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            print_user(user);
        } else {
            google_login_in();
        }
    });
```

And second is how to use "`signInWithRedirect`"?

The link say "To sign in by redirecting to the sign-in page, call `signInWithRedirect`"

So if user is sign in already, and i want to redirect to "`B.html`" page

How can I use this function?

```
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect("B.html");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your flow is generally okay, although you probably do not want to trigger `google_login_in()` from `onAuthStateChanged` for two reasons:

1. The listener may fire `null` during initialization. It is intended to be a positive indicator of login state and only presence of user (not absence) is reliable for this.
2. Browsers will ignore requests to open popup windows that don't originate from user actions. You should attach the sign in to a click event on a button, for instance, or use `signInWithRedirect`.

Which brings me to `signInWithRedirect()` -- this does not imply that your app will redirect but rather than the Firebase Auth process will take place via redirect instead of in a popup window. This *can* be triggered without user interaction, however it will trigger a full-page reload, taking the user away from the current page and then bringing them back.

If you want to redirect to a different URL when the user is authenticated, you should just wait until `onAuthStateChanged` indicates a user is signed in, then redirect with e.g. `window.location = '/B.html'`